# Change place of DOM elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to change places of my dynamic elements in my webpage with jQuery, here is the code which I have this code.

```html
<div class="div1"><label>Name</label></div>
<div class="div2"><label>Address</label></div>
<div class="div3"><label>User No</label></div>
```

and how I want to do with jQuery at run time

```html
<div class="div1"><label>Name</label></div>
<div class="div3"><label>User No</label></div>
<div class="div2"><label>Address</label></div>
```

I want to move `div2` after `div3`. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `.insertAfter(selector)` at this context,

```
$("div.div2").insertAfter(".div3");
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ct8ouL1r/)

Comment: Thank you @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy

Comment: @Stack-overflow-hero Glad to help! And by the way, Try to click on the tick mark present with anyone of the answers here which satisfied you well. Because that action of yours will help the future visitors to spot the correct answer. And this is not a compulsion. :)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try with <kbd>**[`insertBefore(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/)**</kbd> as below:

```
$(".div3").insertBefore(".div2");
```

**Code Snippet**

```js
$(".div3").insertBefore(".div2")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1"><label>Name</label></div>
<div class="div2"><label>Address</label></div>
<div class="div3"><label>User No</label></div>
```